# how to properly use aws rds describe-events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to view all events related to all of my RDS instance for audit purposes.
I am using this

```
aws rds describe-events --source-type db-instance
```

But I am getting an empty result

```
{
    "Events": []
}
```

Even if I include a --source-identifier, it still yields an empty result

Comment: did you make sure that the rds instance is in the default region in ~/.aws/config ? if not add the ```--region``` parameter with the appropriate region

Answer (score 3):

by default it retrieves result for the last an hour, if there are no events to display then it might be empty.

so include flag --duration 3600 (in minutes) to get one day events .. if you go higher then you will get the results ( max 14 days)

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same: adding `--start-time` and `--end-time` fixed it for me. For some reason `--duration` did not.

So something like this should work:

```
aws rds describe-events --start-time 2020-07-24T00:00Z --end-time 2020-07-24T18:00Z
```